# Bitcoins lost in Bitcoin Core?

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, synchronization, wallet.dat, lost-bitcoins

I sent a small amount of bitcoins to my bitcoin core account when I was messing around learning to use bitcoins several years ago. I am trying to access these coins but I never got along to utilizing bitcoin core. My computer is rather bad so it has never fully synced up to the most recent block and my computer likely lacks the space/processing power to do so. Is there a way I can access the public/private keys for that address through bitcoin core and then manage that wallet online? Would anyone be able to walk me thru getting the keys and setting up wallet online?

Answer (score 1):

In bicoin-qt open Help > Debug Window > Console.

An type the following commands.
First you need to list all addresses with funds, look for every line that has an address and take note.

```
listuspent
```

Second, you unlock your wallet

```
walletpassphrase "YOUR-PASS-PHRASE" 120
```

Then for each address, you should get the private key

```
dumpprivkey "1BITCOINADDRESS"
```

take note of every private key and  import them in another wallet. Take care when handling private keys and don't save them in clear text.
Instead of having an online wallet, what you can do is install Electrum which is a SPV wallet and import your private keys there.